# Is there a way to access the "Recent Items" list from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder

The Apple menu "Recent Items" entry is handy, but at times I would like to be able to access it via command line, e.g. to change to a directory I was just working in with a GUI app. Is there a way to get access to at least the last open file or folder from Desktop to terminal?

Failing that, is there a way to access a smart folder from the command line (for example, if I have one that consists of files modified in the past 2 days).

Comment: This **isn’t** an answer but **cd -** puts you back in the immediately previous directory.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like this which is not exactly what you asked for but might be close.

```
mdfind 'kMDItemLastUsedDate >= $time.today()' | grep -vE '^.+Applications.+\.app'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the recent items plist file.

```
    defaults read $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems
```

There's a lot of "noise" in the output. You can filter the "noise" with `grep` and list the last entry with `tail` which should be the last file opened (but not always the case).

```
    defaults read $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems | grep "Name" | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I think you need $HOME/Library/Preferences...

Sure a lot of junk in there.

Comment: I tried this in El Capitan and it didn't work.

Comment: this pref item has disappeared... :(